# React Router v4 Redirecting on form submit

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

Brand new to react, Attempting to redirect to a "homepage" after clicking submit on a "login" page. Tried to follow the react router tutorial.

When I click the submit button on the form and console log the state and fakeAuth.isAuthenticated, they both return true. However, the redirect is not firing.

**Login.js**

```
class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            portalId: "",
            password: "",
            redirectToReferrer: false
        }

        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }


    handleSubmit(e) {
        fakeAuth.authenticate(() => {
            this.setState({
                portalId: this.refs.portalId.value,
                password: this.refs.password.value,
                redirectToReferrer: true
            })
        })
        e.preventDefault();
    }


    render() {
        const redirectToReferrer = this.state.redirectToReferrer;
        if (redirectToReferrer === true) {
            <Redirect to="/home" />
        }
```

**Routes.js**

```
export const fakeAuth = {
    isAuthenticated: false,
    authenticate(cb) {
        this.isAuthenticated = true
        setTimeout(cb, 100)
    },
    signout(cb) {
        this.isAuthenticated = false
        setTimeout(cb, 100)
    }
}

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={() => (
        fakeAuth.isAuthenticated === true
        ? <Component {...this.props}/>
        : <Redirect to="/" />
    )}/> 
)


export default () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
            <Navbar />
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact component={Login} />
                <Route path="/register" exact component={Register} />
                <Route path="/home" exact component={Home} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You have to return `Redirect` in render method (otherwise it will not be rendered and as a result redirection will not happen):

```
  render() {
        const redirectToReferrer = this.state.redirectToReferrer;
        if (redirectToReferrer) {
            return <Redirect to="/home" />
        }
        // ... rest of render method code
   }
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Should have posted earlier instead of spending many hours wasted on this.

Comment: @VincentNguyen You're welcome. Please upvote and accept the answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 11):

I am now able to redirect to the "homepage" by swapping out `<Redirect to="/home" />` with `this.props.history.push("/home");` using `withRouter`. Not sure why the first way would not work though.

Comment: Can you give an example of where you added it?  @Vincent Nguyen

Comment: There is a useful post on the difference between using `history.push` and `redirect` at: https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-programmatically-navigate/

Answer (score 4):

For someone, who uses **Hooks**, have a look here -> https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory
Example of use:

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
let history = useHistory();
        
const onSubmit = () => {
    //code
    history.push(`/${link}/${object.id}`)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `useNavigate` hook is what worked for me. In react-router-dom v6 `useHistory` was replaced with `useNavigate`. Here's the code that solved the issue for me:

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
const navigate = useNavigate();
const onSubmit = () => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // do what you want with your form data
    navigate('/my-path');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When we use  outside our router declaration. You can just use

this.props.history.push('/url')

inside your function call. Should work with react-router-dom