# Component not rendering on redirect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

On submit of a form I want to redirect to another page. My files are as such:

Main.js

```
import Home from '../Home'
import Results from "../Results";

    class Main extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/" component={Home}/>
                    <Route path="/show_parsed_results" exact component={Results}/>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

export default Main;
```

Home.js(Only relevant code is added here.):

```
class Home extends Component {
    state = {
        filepath: '',
        skiplines: 0,
        is_loading: false,
        is_error: false,
        is_success: false,
        err_message: ''
    };

    handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();

        API.post(`path`, path_inputs)
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res);
                console.log(res.data);
                this.setState({
                    is_loading: false,
                    is_success: true
                })
            })
            .catch(err => {
                this.setState({
                    is_error: true,
                    is_loading: false,
                    err_message: err['message']
                })
            })
    };

    render() {
        if (this.state.is_success) {
            return <Redirect to='/show_parsed_results'/>
        } else {
            return (
                .....render form here.....
            );
        }
    }
}

export default Home;
```

Results.js(The component to be rendered after submission)

```
class Results extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <Button className="center-align">Show Product Price Per Place </Button>
                <Button className="center-align">Show Sales Aggregation Per Place </Button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Results;
```

I have redirected if the is_success variable is true to the path `show_parsed_results`. In my router I have mapped this path to my `Results` component.

But on submission, the page is being redirected but it is empty. Its not picking up the Results component code at all. What am I missing here?

I understand this could be duplicate of [Redirecting on form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49738249/react-router-v4-redirecting-on-form-submit), but I have followed the exact same procedure and am not able to achieve the redirection correctly. Can some help in finding what I am missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: adding tree structure and import statements.

Tree Structure:

```
.
├── App.css
├── App.test.js
├── Home
│   └── index.js
├── Main
│   └── index.js
├── Results
│   └── index.js
├── api
│   └── index.js
```

Comment: After the redirect what is your URL ? Are you correctly importing the component Results inside `Main.js` ?

Comment: Yes, I have added the tree structure and the import statements from Main.js. You can check it too. Thanks

Comment: And what is the URL after submitting ?

Comment: Is there any error ourput?

Comment: I think your import is erronous. It should be like that: import Results from "../Results/index";

Comment: But my Home component is in the same structure and it is being picked up correctly. I tried nevertheless with index appended. It still does not work

Comment: @Zhe no there is no error output but there is warning that says - `Warning: You tried to redirect to the same route you're currently on: "/show_parsed_results" `

Comment: Can you add 'exact' before path of both Route

Comment: @mstfyldz thanks. that worked. if you want, add it as an answer and I will accept. Also any idea why this fixes the issue?

Comment: Hi @leoOrion to help others for help I added it as answer with explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add 'exact' before path of both Route

As explained in that question:  [React : difference between <Route exact path="/" /> and <Route path="/" />](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162311/react-difference-between-route-exact-path-and-route-path)

the router will go through all of our defined routes and return the FIRST match it finds