# How can I handle a regular form with no AJAX call on React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am attempting to hit an endpoint `https://api.com/signup.ashx` which has issues with CORS. So I was asked to make the API call without axios nor fetch or anything like that.

So I did this:

```js
const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    let error = false
    let message = ""

    Object.keys(value).forEach((element) => {
      let val = value[element]
      if (!val) {
        error = true
        message = "Please complete all required fields."
      }

      if (element == "email" && val && !validateEmail(val)) {
        error = true
        message = "Please enter valid email address"
      }
    })

    if (error) {
      alert(message)
    } else {
      try {
        console.log("succesful response")
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("error", error)
      }
    }

    event.preventDefault()
  }

return (
      <form
        id="signup"
        name="signup"
        method="post"
        autocomplete="off"
        onsubmit={handleSubmit}
        action="https://api.com/signup.ashx"
      >...</form>
)
```

We do not care if the page reloads. The problem is that it reloads and takes the user to an error route:

`locahost:8000/?result=error` which makes me think that the call to the endpoint isn't working.

Regarding the CORS situation, it is not on me. I was just asked to do it as I mentioned.

So do you have any idea what the problem with my code is?

Comment: Have you checked the actual HTTP response via the Network developer tab?

Comment: @Pointy it is not even doing the API call. I mean, in the network tab, I don't see that URL being hit.

Answer (score 0):

Navigation in react is controlled by routers. You have to use router instead of form's action. Refer [React Router v4 Redirecting on form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49738249/react-router-v4-redirecting-on-form-submit)

Also the `event.preventDefault` should be the first statement in the submit function.